# Why is my compiler throwing a "Conversion loses (const) qualifiers" error when I call a const getter function?

Tags: c++, qt, class, constants

I am writing a clone of the classic artillery game Scorched Earth (as if there aren't enough of those already), and have run into a problem which confounds me. I have a getter function in my Player class, which returns a const copy of the player's name.

```
const std::string Player::getName()
{
    return this->m_name;
}
```

I am using the getter to set the text of a text label on my viewport to reflect the name of the player whose turn it currently is.

```
void Tanx::handlePlayerEvents(const Player& player)
{
    QObject::connect(&player, &Player::aimChanged, this, [=](int angle) {this->angleSlider->setValue(angle);  });
    this->playerNameDisplay->setText((QString::fromStdString(player.getName())));
}
```

My compiler is throwing these errors, even though my return value is const, and the QString::fromStdString takes a const reference to an std::string.

```
1>C:\Users\Dominic\source\repos\Tanx\tanx.cpp(85,74): error C2662: 'const std::string Player::getName(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Player' to 'Player &'
1>C:\Users\Dominic\source\repos\Tanx\tanx.cpp(85,59): message : Conversion loses qualifiers
1>C:\Users\Dominic\source\repos\Tanx\Player.h(63,20): message : see declaration of 'Player::getName' (compiling source file tanx.cpp)
```

I am having difficulty figuring out what the issue is, and I figure it will probably be embarrassingly clear to somebody with actual coding skill. Thank you for your help!

[EDIT]
Thank you to David Schwartz! Declaring the function, not just the return value as const worked perfectly. Also, a good suggestion to return a const reference to avoid copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const std::string Player::getName()
```

The `const` here doesn't do anything. You're returning a value -- the value of `m_name`. A *value* cannot be `const` since changing a value always produces a different value.

What you wanted was a `const` function, one that it is permitted to call on a `const`-qualified member. You define them as follows:

```
std::string Player::getName() const
```

Also, it's pretty common to have a getter like this return a `const std::string&` to avoid an unnecessary copy. Of course, it does make sense to `const`-qualify something returned by reference.